# Calculating cannibalization/attribution in R

Tags: r, algorithm

I have a metric that is distributed among four categories `a, b, c, d`.

Over a period of time I track the movement in the metric for each category.  The sum of these movements represents a quantity that has either left or entered the system from elsewhere ('external').

```
# SETUP -------------------------------------------------------------------

categories <- letters[1:4]
set.seed(1)
movements <- lapply(categories, function(...) {round(runif(10, -10,10))*10})
names(movements) <- categories
movements[['external']] <- Reduce(`+`, movements)*-1
problem <- as.data.frame(movements)
problem

     a   b    c   d external
1  -50 -60   90   0       20
2  -30 -60  -60  20      130
3   10  40   30   0      -80
4   80 -20  -70 -60       70
5  -60  50  -50  70      -10
6   80   0  -20  30      -90
7   90  40 -100  60      -90
8   30 100  -20 -80      -30
9   30 -20   70  40     -120
10 -90  60  -30 -20       80
```

Where some categories have undergone positive movements and others have undergone negative movements, we can infer a transfer within the system.

```
# ADD TRANSFER COLUMNS AND INITIALISE TO 0 --------------------------------

transfer_matrix <- combn(c(categories, 'external'), 2)
transfer_list <- combn(c(categories, 'external'), 2, simplify=F)
problem[,sapply(transfer_list, paste, collapse='.')] <- 0
paste(names(problem), collapse=', ')

[1] "a, b, c, d, external, a.b, a.c, a.d, a.external, b.c, b.d, b.external, c.d, c.external, d.external"
```

For example `a` has decreased by 50 and `c` has increased by 90, so we can infer there is a transfer from `a` to `c` which will be stored in the variable `a.c`.

The rule for calculating the transfers is proportional.  So when 'a' has decrease by 50 and `b` has decreased by 60, then 50/(50+60) of the increase in `c` should be attributed to `'a'`, and 60/(50+60) of the increase in `c` should be attributed to `b`.  And similarly for the transfers in and out of the system.

Below shows the full manual calculation for all of the variables I need, for the first row:

```
# MANUAL CALCULATION ------------------------------------------------------

row_limit <- 1  # change to e.g. 1:10
problem[row_limit, 'a.b'] <- 0
problem[row_limit, 'a.c'] <- 90*(-50/(-50+-60))
problem[row_limit, 'a.d'] <- 0
problem[row_limit, 'a.external'] <- 20 * -50/(-50+-60)
problem[row_limit, 'b.c'] <- 90*(-60/(-50+-60))
problem[row_limit, 'b.d'] <- 0 
problem[row_limit, 'b.external'] <- 20 * -60/(-50+-60)
problem[row_limit, 'c.d'] <- 0
problem[row_limit, 'c.external'] <- 0
problem[row_limit, 'd.external'] <- 0
```

Note that since `a.c = -c.a` only a subset of all possible transfers need to be calculated.

My question is, how can I code the above calculations programmatically, in a concise and efficient way to handle 10-20 categories and a large number of rows?

I typically use data.table but open to any suggestions of packages to use.

Below is some code for checking the output:

```
# CHECKING ----------------------------------------------------------------

check <- function(problem, category, categories, transfer_list, transfer_matrix) {
  out_columns <- sapply(transfer_list[transfer_matrix[1,] == category], paste, collapse='.')
  in_columns <- sapply(transfer_list[transfer_matrix[2,] == category], paste, collapse='.')
  stopifnot(length(c(out_columns, in_columns)) == length(categories)-1)

  out_sum <- 0
  if(length(out_columns) == 1) {
    out_sum <- problem[,out_columns]
  } else if(length(out_columns) > 1) {
    out_sum <- Reduce(`+`, problem[,out_columns])
  }

  in_sum <- 0     
  if(length(in_columns) == 1) {
    in_sum <- problem[,in_columns]
  }
  else if(length(in_columns) > 1) {
    in_sum <- Reduce(`+`, problem[,in_columns])
  }

  lhs <- out_sum - in_sum
  rhs <- -problem[, category]
  sprintf('%s vs %s',lhs, rhs)
}

# For each category, actual vs expected
sapply(c(categories,'external'), check, problem=problem, categories=c(categories,'external'), transfer_list=transfer_list,transfer_matrix=transfer_matrix)

      a          b           c            d         
 [1,] "50 vs 50" "60 vs 60"  "-90 vs -90" "0 vs 0"  
 [2,] "0 vs 30"  "0 vs 60"   "0 vs 60"    "0 vs -20"
 [3,] "0 vs -10" "0 vs -40"  "0 vs -30"   "0 vs 0"  
 [4,] "0 vs -80" "0 vs 20"   "0 vs 70"    "0 vs 60" 
 [5,] "0 vs 60"  "0 vs -50"  "0 vs 50"    "0 vs -70"
 [6,] "0 vs -80" "0 vs 0"    "0 vs 20"    "0 vs -30"
 [7,] "0 vs -90" "0 vs -40"  "0 vs 100"   "0 vs -60"
 [8,] "0 vs -30" "0 vs -100" "0 vs 20"    "0 vs 80" 
 [9,] "0 vs -30" "0 vs 20"   "0 vs -70"   "0 vs -40"
[10,] "0 vs 90"  "0 vs -60"  "0 vs 30"    "0 vs 20"
```

Comment: Could you simplify this down to a small reproducible example? Maybe simplify the issue you're facing? This would currently take a while to comprehend and work out what you're trying to do/how to do it better, and in which case would be a "write my code" question, which isn't allowed.

Comment: Hmm...  did you have any issues running the code/reproducing the results?  I agree that it's a lengthy question...  I could remove some of the code, e.g. the transfer columns block & the checking block if you think it would help.

Comment: I'm not going to run all of that and try to debug it. If you have a specific issue then whittle it down to a general example of that.

Comment: Looks more of a question for codereview.stackexchange.com to me.

Comment: I had considered it, but that community specifically requires the code to already be written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one idea. I believe the output matches what you want.

```
#x is a row from problem df
#y is a column from transfer_matrix
check_pairs <- function(x,y){
    #split y into which columns are being compared . e.g. if col 1 is 'd' vs 'external', then ...
    a <- y[1]  #would be 'd'
    b <- y[2]  #would be 'external'
    #if both pos, both neg, or one val is 0, then return 0
    if( sign(x[a]) == sign(x[b]) | sign(x[[a]]) == 0){
        return(0)
    }else{ #else return formula from your manual calculation
        return( x[[b]] * x[[a]] / sum( x[sign(x)==sign(x[[a]]) ] ) )
    }
}

#for each row of the problem matrix, compare to each column of the transfer_matrix
check_matrix_cols <- function(x){ 
    return( apply(transfer_matrix, 2, function(y) check_pairs(x,y)) )
}

problem[,-seq(length(c(categories, 'external')))] <- t( apply(problem, 1, check_matrix_cols) )

sapply(c(categories,'external'), check, problem=problem, categories=c(categories,'external'), transfer_list=transfer_list,transfer_matrix=transfer_matrix)

          a            b              c            d            external      
 [1,] "50 vs 50"   "60 vs 60"     "-90 vs -90" "0 vs 0"     "-20 vs -20"  
 [2,] "30 vs 30"   "60 vs 60"     "60 vs 60"   "-20 vs -20" "-130 vs -130"
 [3,] "-10 vs -10" "-40 vs -40"   "-30 vs -30" "0 vs 0"     "80 vs 80"    
 [4,] "-80 vs -80" "20 vs 20"     "70 vs 70"   "60 vs 60"   "-70 vs -70"  
 [5,] "60 vs 60"   "-50 vs -50"   "50 vs 50"   "-70 vs -70" "10 vs 10"    
 [6,] "-80 vs -80" "0 vs 0"       "20 vs 20"   "-30 vs -30" "90 vs 90"    
 [7,] "-90 vs -90" "-40 vs -40"   "100 vs 100" "-60 vs -60" "90 vs 90"    
 [8,] "-30 vs -30" "-100 vs -100" "20 vs 20"   "80 vs 80"   "30 vs 30"    
 [9,] "-30 vs -30" "20 vs 20"     "-70 vs -70" "-40 vs -40" "120 vs 120"  
[10,] "90 vs 90"   "-60 vs -60"   "30 vs 30"   "20 vs 20"   "-80 vs -80"
```